# INSTALACIÓN DE BERT

Tags: python

estoy intentando instalar BERT as service utilizando pip y me da error diciendo que la sintaxis es inválida, alguien me lo pude aclarar

```
pip install bert-serving-server  # server
pip install bert-serving-client  # client, independent of `bert-serving-server`

pip install transformer  # server
          ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Puedes poner el mensaje de error en concreto? Y en qué momento te da el error?

Comment: ¿Dónde has puesto esas líneas? Se supone que has de ejecutarlas en una terminal. Quizás es que las has puesto como parte de un script python? Al margen de eso, te recomiendo que uses entornos virtuales para instalar paquetes, evitando así interferir en los paquetes instalados a nivel de sistema

Answer (score 1):

Buen día,

Es buena practica crear un archivo `requirements.txt` cuando se quiere instalar múltiples librerías por `pip`.

Por esto te recomiendo lo siguiente:

1. crea un archivo en el directorio actual donde pondrás todas las librerías que quieres instalar.

Nota: si tienes `linux` te regalo este comando para que lo utilices para tu caso particular

```
cat > requirements.txt
bert-serving-server
bert-serving-client
transformer
```

Finaliza con un `ctrl+C`

2. El archivo final debe verse algo así:

   bert-serving-server

   bert-serving-client

   transformer
3. Listo ahora solo tenemos que decirle a `pip` que cargue los paquetes desde este archivo con la siguiente linea de comando

`python -m pip install -r requirements.txt`

Si tienes algún otro error comenta y te ayudare a solucionarlo

Un saludo :)